# Maximum price display first collection

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection

I want to display Maxprice display first how to get that collection

```
$categoryIds = array(469);//category id
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryIds));
$Collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $products->getAllIds()));;
$Collection->addAttributeToSelect(array(
                                   'image','small_image',
                                   'name',
                                   'short_description'
                   ))
->addFieldToFilter('visibility', array(
                               Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                               Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
                   )) 


->joinField('qty',
             'cataloginventory/stock_item',
             'qty',
             'product_id=entity_id',
             '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
             'left')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array("gt" => 0))

->addFinalPrice()
->getSelect()
->where('price_index.final_price' < 'price_index.price')->Order('price_index.final_price', 'DESC');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that

```
$categoryIds = array(469);//category id


      $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryIds));
$Collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $products->getAllIds()));;
$Collection->addAttributeToSelect(array(
                                   'image','small_image',
                                   'name',
                                   'short_description'
                   ))
->addFieldToFilter('visibility', array(
                               Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                               Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
                   )) 


->joinField('qty',
             'cataloginventory/stock_item',
             'qty',
             'product_id=entity_id',
             '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
             'left')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array("gt" => 0))

->addFinalPrice()
->getSelect()
->where('price_index.final_price' < 'price_index.price');
$Collection->addAttributeToSort('price', 'desc');
```

Comment: I already try this it won't show that block also

Comment: update the answer kindly try that and feedback..

Comment: I will check and let you know i got confused

Comment: it works for ASC order

Comment: yes just change DESC to ASC

Comment: i try that also no change same

Comment: did you remove that order in code `->setOrder('price', 'ASC'`

Comment: yes after change this if both price equal that also display

Comment: can you paste your recent code?

Comment: yes recent code only i used

Comment: paste your code in question so i can see what is wrong with your code

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: update code test and working...

Comment: Now also same..

Comment: what is out can you show that?

Comment: Can you please check this tt.collagekingapp.com

Comment: complete page link ...

Comment: Same home page only deal of the day slider

Comment: it goes from 159 to 13499 what else you want it is ASC order.

Comment: i set this ->where('price_index.final_price' < 'price_index.price')->Order('price_index.max_price', 'DESC'); but it showing ASC

Comment: update and test too for `DESC` kindly check and feedback me

Comment: Now it show random check that link

Comment: remove the scroll and check what is displaying.

Comment: i removed scroll now also same

Comment: after testing and lot searching this solution work for you. make sure in attribute `price` you set `Used for Sorting in Product Listing` `Yes`

Comment: It's partially work thanks for your help i will check it

Comment: is this worked http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102237/invoice-button-not-showing/102274#102274

Answer (score 0):

In Magento,you can sort a product collection by `addAttributeToSort()`.

If you *want to sort product collection by final price*,then Use `getSelect()->order("price_index.final_price DESC")` , as f**inal_price is  not an attribute.**

Also, if ***you want to sort by price*** then you can use *`addAttributeToSort('price','DESC')`*;

Comment: I will check and let you know i got confused